# How to resolve typescript error for topojson package?

Tags: typescript, topojson

Please forgive the naive question; I'm new to Typescript. In javascript, I can use [topojson.mesh](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) to create a mesh object like this:

```
import us from "./counties-albers-10m.json"
topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, (a, b) => a !== b))
```

When I try to do this in Typescript, I get this warning:

```
Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type "Topology" TS2345
```

I have `@types/topojson` installed as well. Can anyone help me debug this? I do not understand enough about typescript to understand what the problem is.

More broadly, how does one debug errors like this? I find all sorts of type issues with 3rd party packages and do not know how to assign my javascript objects the right type in many cases. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal git repo for debugging

Comment: Using typescript shouldn't generate a different output than using js. If you have a compilation issue you should provide all the versions of the packages in use (pacakge.json). Also if you are using an IDE/editor with executing compilation on the fly it is common to not have the same configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once I installed `@types/topojson` I could import the required types from `topojson-specification` like this:

```
import * as topojson from 'topojson-client';
import { GeometryObject, Topology } from 'topojson-specification';
import us from '../counties-albers-10m.json';

topojson.mesh(
  (us as unknown) as Topology,
  us.objects.states as GeometryObject,
  (a: GeometryObject, b: GeometryObject) => a !== b
);
```

> More broadly, how does one debug errors like this?

To debug this kind of thing, I use my IDE (VS Code) to inspect the methods, like the `.mesh` method and see the types it is expecting. I also used the *Go To Definition* functionality (⌘ + click on Mac) to view the type definitions:
[image]

Going to the type definition file also showed me where they imported the types from.

There was a part about this I couldn't figure out though. When you import JSON in TypeScript it automatically infers the types, but these automatic types seemed to conflict with the `@types/topojson` ones for a number of reasons (e.g. `number[] !== [number, number]`). That is why I needed to cast to `unknown` first before casting to the correct type. This may not be the optimal solution, but I am not aware of a way to describe the typings for a JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone help me debug this?

The error basically says:

Property `type` of your passed in `us` object literal from `"./counties-albers-10m.json"` has the type `string`, but typings from `@types/topojson` *expect* it to be the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `"Topology"`, which is more specific than a widened `string`. For example you cannot do this:

```
const wideString: string = "something"
const stringLiteral: "Topology" = wideString // error, string not assignable to type "Topology"
```

When checking typings for [`mesh`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/topojson-client/index.d.ts#L31) and its first function argument `topology` with type [`Topology`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/topojson-specification/index.d.ts#L27), you can indeed see, that the types are exactly like determined above.

So why is that? Let's take a simple JSON file:

```
{ "a": "foo", "b": 42 }
```

When importing this file with `import us from "./counties-albers-10m.json"`, then `us` type actually is:

```
type US = typeof us; // type US = { a: string; b: number; }
```

**TypeScript *widens* the property literal types inferred from the JSON file**: `"foo"` becomes `string` and `42` becomes `number` respectively. This behavior is [intentional](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26552), but there is also a feature request asking for [more flexbility](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32063) with `as const` to give you the narrow, exact type.

#### Solution

Use a type assertion (`as`) to convert the imported `us` object to either `Topology` or a custom type.

```
import { Topology } from "topojson-specification" // needed type for mesh API
// alternatively use a custom compatible json type

import us_ from "./counties-albers-10m.json"

const us: Topology = us_ as Topology; 

topojson.mesh(us, ...) // this should work now
```

> how does one debug errors like this?

The error message was quite informative, I think you just weren't aware of string literal types and/or JSON widening. In general you can also peek into third library types with an IDE like VS Code to see, what shape is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation. It's very helpful! One issue I am having is when I `import us_ from "./counties-albers-10m.json"` and try to generate `const us: Topology = us_ as Topology;`, TS says: `type 'Topology<Objects<GeoJsonProperties>>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  The types of 'transform.scale' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1  TS2352`. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is what is going on: we "cast" the imported `us_` json object to `Topology` via `as`. This type assertion roughly checks, if `us` really is of the type `Topology` you want to have - if `us` is assignable to `Topology` *or* `Topology` is assignable to `us`, then the compiler thinks your assertion is valid. So it depends on the data structure you have saved in `"./counties-albers-10m.json"`. If it looks like `Topology`, it should work with `as`. If you are sure, everything is fine, you can use a hard type assertion `const us = us_ as unknown as Topology` to disable all checks.